# Magento 1 'sign up for newsletter' on checkout onepage

Tags: magento-1.9

I've searched and searched how to add the **'sign up for newsletter'** checkbox (same as on  the `customer/account/create/` page), to the `/checkout/onepage` page,  but can't find any definitive answer.

I'd like it at the 'billing information' stage if possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with a small extension ... here the most important steps:

- create your own extension
- `app/code/community/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/config.xml`

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <[Vendor]_[Module]>
               <version>1.0.0</version>
           </[Vendor]_[Module]>
       </modules>
       <global>
           <helpers>
               <newslettersubscribe>
                   <class>[Vendor]_[Module]_Helper</class>
               </newslettersubscribe>
           </helpers>
           <models>
               <newslettersubscribe>
                   <class>[Vendor]_[Module]_Model</class>
               </newslettersubscribe>
           </models>
       </global>
       <frontend>
           <events>
               <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
                   <observers>
                       <newslettersubscribe>
                           <type>model</type>
                           <class>newslettersubscribe/observer</class>
                           <method>subscribeEventOnepageSaveOrderAfter</method>
                       </newslettersubscribe>
                   </observers>
               </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
               <controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
                   <observers>
                       <newslettersubscribe>
                           <type>model</type>
                           <class>newslettersubscribe/observer</class>
                           <method>subscribeEventSaveBilling</method>
                       </newslettersubscribe>
                   </observers>
               </controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
           </events>
           <layout>
               <updates>
                   <newslettersubscribe>
                       <file>[Vendor]/[Module].xml</file>
                   </newslettersubscribe>
               </updates>
           </layout>
       </frontend>
   </config>
  ```
- `app/code/community/[Vendor]/[Module]/Model/Observer.php`

  ```
   class [Vendor]_[Module]_Model_Observer
   {
       public function subscribeEventSaveBilling(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
       {
           $billing = $observer->getEvent()
               ->getControllerAction()
               ->getRequest()
               ->getParam('billing', array());

           $willSubscribe = isset($billing['subscribe']);
           Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setWillSubscribe($willSubscribe);

           return $this;
       }

       public function subscribeEventOnepageSaveOrderAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
       {
           $willSubscribe = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getWillSubscribe();

           if ((bool)$willSubscribe) {
               $email = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getData('customer_email');
               Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email, true);
           }
           return $this;
       }
   }
  ```
- `app/code/community/[Vendor]/[Module]/Helper/Data.php`

  ```
   class [Vendor]_[Module]_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
   {
       /** @var string $_moduleName Module name */
       protected $_moduleName = '[Vendor]_[Module]';

       public function isSubscribed()
       {
           $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
           if ($customer) {
               $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
               $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
               if ($subscriber) {
                   return $subscriber->isSubscribed();
               }
           }
       }
   }
  ```
- `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/[Vendor]/[Module].xml`

  ```
   <layout version="0.1.0">
       <checkout_onepage_index>
           <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
               <block type="core/template" name="form.additional.info">
                   <action method="setTemplate">
                       <template>[Vendor]/[Module]/subscribe.phtml</template>
                   </action>
               </block>
           </reference>
       </checkout_onepage_index>
   </layout>
  ```
- `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/[Vendor]/[Module]/subscribe.phtml`

  ```
   <?php
   $helper = Mage::helper('newslettersubscribe');
   ?>

   <li class="control">
       <input type="checkbox" name="billing[subscribe]" id="billing:subscribe" value="1" <?php if ($helper->isSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
       <label for="billing:subscribe"><?php echo $helper->getFrontendLabel() ?></label>
   </li>
  ```

If I havn't missed anything this should a checkbox to your checkout billing section. If you want the checkbox at review step, read here [Newsletter subscription at the checkout review](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206581/newsletter-subscription-at-the-checkout-review/214952#214952).

Comment: Thank you sv3n - I will be working on this tomorrow and will report back.

Comment: Hi sv3n With little knowledge of how to create extensions, I think I need step by step instructions. I'm confused at step 1 :-) 
I did manage to create the file and folder structure for the module and get it to display in the Admin/Advanced/Advanced Disable Modules Output list, but as to where the code above goes, I'm lost.

Comment: @Andy updated answer. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Hi sv3n - again thank you!
I created my extension (AJH_NewsSub) and can see it active in Admin.
I replaced all [Vendor]/[Module] with AJH/NewsSub logic and created the following:
app/code/community/AJH/NewsSub/etc/config.xml
app/code/community/AJH/NewsSub/etc/Model/Observer.php
app/code/community/AJH/NewsSub/etc/Helper/Data.php
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/AJH/NewsSub.xml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/AJH/NewsSub/subscribe.phtml
This didn't display the subscribe checkbox. I am using a custom theme and will give detail in my next reply.

Comment: My custom theme uses the following to display the billing section of my checkout:
frontend\argento\default\template\persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
I've tried several places for the NewsSub.xml and subscribe.phtml files but no luck so far.
This is helping me to understand the structure of Magento better and i'd love to get this working if possible.

Comment: Also changed the 'newslettersubscribe' to the module name 'NewsSub' ??

Comment: Hi sv3nI  - I wonder If I could send you my files and folder structure for your advice? I've looked at similar modules and just can't figure out why the subscribe checkbox isn't displaying. It would be great to see this working, plus it would help me to investigate making further modules. Please let me know If I can email you.
Many Thanks
Andy